# Hibernate 3.0 + ElementCollection class missing

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hibernate3, java

I created a small desktop project using Hibernate, to understand how enterprise patterns are applied in there.

I'm using annotations, and wrote a class to wrap my session factory

```
public class Hibernation {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static{
        try{
            //sesionFactory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch(Throwable e){
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

}
```

However, whenever i try to run it, I get this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.ElementCollection

The jars in my classpath do not seem to have that class inside them

```
hibernate3.jar
jpa.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.0.1.jar
```

I've looked around for that class, but I can't find where to download it from. Any idea what jar file i'm missing? I looked inside [javaee.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/GHI/Downloadjavaeejar.htm), where there are many javax.persistence.*** clases, but its not there either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the newer version of Hibernate.
The version should be greater than 3.5 or its better use Hibernate 4.0.
Please use the following link to download the suitable version http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't take 
javax.persistence_2.0_preview.jar 
from 1.2.0 OSGi bundles zip if you test Hibernate 3.5.0 beta 2,
because it is not complete! 
For example class javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder is missing there.

Take following jar indeed: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/java-persistence/jpa-api/2.0-cr-1/jpa-api-2.0-cr-1.jar

Generally it is recommended to take all hiberante 3hrd-party jars out from
this repository (repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/)

regards
G.D.

Answer (score 0):

Try having `ejb3-persistence-3.3.2.Beta1.jar` (or another version if you wish) on your classpath, and remove the other JPA jars.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem this morning, and eventually found the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689241/problem-with-annotationsessionfactorybean).

You can download the EclipseLink JPA 2.0 preview implementation from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php).

I downloaded the 1.2.0 OSGi bundles zip, and then extracted the `javax.persistence_2.0_preview.jar` file, which seems to do the trick with Hibernate 3.5.0 beta 2.

Comment: the question is about Hibernate

Comment: @Bozho - yes, and the answer is about how to get it to work with the new persistence API Draft, hence the mention of 3.5 beta 2 at the end of the answer...